# Strange behaviour of Laravel application behind HAPROXY load balancer

Tags: laravel, load-balancing, haproxy

All forms in Laravel behind a Haproxy load balancer are prepended by an http URL in the form action.

SSL port is forwarded to HTTP port(80) on each app server in haproxy. Everything else works fine.

However, the form template generated by

```
<form action="{{ route('your.route.name') }}" method="post">
    <!-- Your form fields and submit button go here -->
</form>
```

prepends http://web_url instead of https://web_url. We have provided https://web_url in the .env file on all servers.

So when checking the source we see

```
<form
              class="form-horizontal mt-3"
              id="loginform"
              action="http://web_url/login"
              method="POST"
            >
```

What could be the issue.

Everything else works absolutely fine. Why is the APP_URL not being picked up, and the http:// is prepended instead of https://

Comment: Typically a well configured proxy adds the forwarded protocol the [Forwarded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Forwarded) header or the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header. Laravel can detect that if you configure [trusted proxies](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies). It's possible you need to first configure HAProxy to add these headers if it is not doing so already

Comment: Despite setting up trusted proxies, problem persists

Comment: Check the incoming request headers if the forwarded headers are being set by HAProxy and try to configure it to send them if they are not

Comment: They are set up as haproxy docs, as well as NGINX docs. When we access the app server directly everything works correctly. Only via haproxy we see that all >\< for action = " " urls are set to http://. We tried hard coding it app_url to .env file with an https:// it's not picking up